# Select element where attribute contains a certain substring

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Looking at the following extract from an `xml` file, if there are multiple instances of activity how would I use xpath to return the value of `name` (`Test Name`) where id attribute of activity contains `5WnweCI2lzT`?

```
<activity type="http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/module" id="http://5gISGNPekh5_course_id/5WnweCI2lzT">
    <name lang="und">Test</name>
    <description lang="und">Test</description>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//activity[contains(@id,'5WnweCI2lzT')]/name/text()
```

Note that this will return multiple results where more than one node contains the identifier.